# TypeScript Interface Function Field Contravariance Type Error

Tags: typescript, interface, typeerror, covariance, contravariance

I have the following type, which establishes that all properties are going to be functions, which accept either no arguments, or a single argument of type `Record<string, any>`:

```
type FnTrait = Record<
  string,
  (input?: Record<string, any>) => any
>;
```

I attempt extend this type into another interface (which I want to have the same constraint).

```
interface HasFn extends FnTrait {
  someFn(): string; // no problem
  anotherFn(o: {id: string}): number; // ts error 2411
}
```

This produces an error on `anotherFn`: `Property 'anotherFn' of type '(o: { id: string; }) => number' is not assignable to string index type '(input?: Record<string | number | symbol, any> | undefined) => any'.`

Why is it that `someFn` produces no error, while `anotherFn` produces ts error 2411? It seems that this narrowing should be allowed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an instance of [function types being *contravariant* in their parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)#Function_types).  The word "contravariant" means "varies in the opposite way".  If you make a function's parameter more *specific* (narrow), you are making the function type itself more *general* (wide).  That means instead of making `HasFn` a *subtype* of `FnTrait` (which is what `extends` means), you are sort of making it a *supertype*.  This is not allowed, and violates the principle of [substitutability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

In particular,
`anotherFn()` is in error because it requires that its argument have a `string`-valued `id` property, while `FnTrait["anotherFn"]` does not.  It is expected that you can call any property of a `FnTrait` with either no parameters, or with a single parameter of just about any type.  But a `HasFn` might explode if you call its `anotherFn()` method without a parameter, or with a parameter missing the right sort of `id` property.  Therefore, as defined, `HasFn` is not assignable to `FnTrait`, despite being declared to extend it:

```
const hasFn: HasFn = {
  someFn: () => "",
  anotherFn: o => o.id.length
}
const fnTrait: FnTrait = hasFn;
fnTrait.anotherFn({ a: 123 }); // okay at compile time, explodes at runtime
```

Since `anotherFn()` means you can't safely substitute a `FnTrait` value where a `HasFn` value is requested, `FnTrait` fails to be assignable to `HasFn`, and you get an error.

---

The reason why `someFn()` is *not* in error is because [a function of fewer parameters is assignable to a function that takes more parameters](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-with-fewer-parameters-assignable-to-functions-that-take-more-parameters).  This is because `someFn()` will, by necessity, ignore any parameters passed into it, so it is safe to treat it as a function which might possibly receive a parameter:

```
fnTrait.someFn({ a: 123 }); // okay at compile time and runtime
```

This works for the same reason `anotherFn()` fails: substitutability.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgdgFQE4EMCWwoF4oCUIDGA9kgCYA8UAUFFAM7BJpwDmANDVABTNgCuwAPwAuPIRIUGTVmygo4IAHwBKbIrkKqigNxU9zYBCQAzFAWgAJFHXhQIAD0NxSdWIlQYoAb050iAWwh4LmVRKWYWbSgAemioOCIoMCQiACMAGwh-TnkiYAALI2CiUS8oNFIwxgioAF9Q+L5-VKMo2KhgVyMUpCgAJgAWAEYhqlq9YjgGKHzreFErGzhsb18AoLhRELUoACJdjlpcgqLNqESsdSIAOgrrzNYCsapJ6eN3dGBReGRPldmlrp3r8MNdjoUkMEyihREM+gBmOrKNpxIgAaxQIDkmGI-jAaEyHTQgVkDjA6SIpAgrhQmCQfDgwGJED0wI8wGufkCULksIRSJR5wxWNpUFx+MJTMCGlIUHpjOZQA)

Comment: thank you for your tremendous description! One more question: what is the most minimal way to enable users to impose the method argument type constraint?... `extends FnTrait` is clean. Any other ways you can recommend that don't produce the contravariance error?